# How to upgrade the chrome browser version Android 7.0 emulator in android studio

Tags: android-emulator

I have created a Virtual Device with the Android flavor I want (Android 7.0) but it has a version of Chrome that I'd like to update to a specific version. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 7):

For me it was simple steps:

1. Open Android emulator from AVD (Mine was Google Pixel 2 - v9.0),
2. Ensure Android emulator has opened successfully by `$ adb devices`(It will give you the Android emulator device name, e.g: emulator-5554)
3. Now download the Google Chrome apk from [apkmirror](https://www.apkmirror.com), Mine was Version: [76.0.3809.111 (380911115) x86](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-76-0-3809-111-release/google-chrome-fast-secure-76-0-3809-111-2-android-apk-download/)
4. Now use this command to install the downloaded Google chrome apk to the opened Android emulator: `$ adb install /path/to/downloaded/chrome/apk`

> *NOTE: Make sure no other emulator or real Android device is connected, `$ adb devices` should return you the single connected device*

5. Above command must return **Success**
6. Open Chrome browser on Android device and check the version, it must match with the downloaded chrome version.
7. Done.

Comment: after doing that, opening chrome crash the emulator.

Comment: two notes, first make sure you install the chrome version for your arch, second make sure to cool boot after the install the new chrome version

Answer (score 4):

Having run into this and bashed thru a few useful sites, it turns out this is rather easy BUT you have to make sure you get the right APK. With thanks to https://www.inflectra.com/support/knowledgebase/kb276.aspx

First start your emulator in writable mode. Put your virtual device name after -avd parameter.

Step 1:
In Terminal execute this command:

```
$ $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd Samsung_Galaxy_S7_API_24 -writable-system
```

Your android emulator should now be open.

Step 2:
Download the apk you want from https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/

Mine was https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-64-0-3282-123-release/#downloads

Step 3:
Once it downloads, drag and drop that `.apk` file onto your emulator.

Wait a few minutes and then open Chrome on that device. It should be the new version.

You can confirm that by going to https://www.whatsmyua.info/

Comment: `bash: emulator/emulator: No such file or directory`

Comment: ok I figure out that I need to go to `cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/` to run the emulator command

Comment: @shamaseen As of release 25.3.0 (March 2017) Emulator released separately from SDK Tools https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#25-3 that means .../sdk/emulator/ is a new path

Comment: The file being downloaded from apkmirror has extension of "apkm". It won't allow me to install. Changing it to be "apk" will not work as well, as i am having an error message. I do not want to use the installer of apkmirror.

Comment: @NisimNaim don't change the file extension, instead download the one in the list that says APK next to it (in a grey rectangle).