# WebView Component in Xamarin.Android Emulator do not use the current browser version

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, android-emulator

I'm trying to load a website which requires a newer version of chrome. So I have created a new device for the emulation and installed the new chrome version by [How to upgrade the chrome browser version Android 7.0 emulator in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300733/how-to-upgrade-the-chrome-browser-version-android-7-0-emulator-in-android-studio).
I've already checked whether the new chrome version is installed by opening the chrome app which shows me the right version tag.

BUT if I open my Xamarin App with the WebView. The WebView seems to use still the older version.
I've checked this by Debugging WebView via Chrome Inspection. (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-debugging-webview/)

Any ideas or experience how the WebView choose the browser-engine and how to fix this.

Not sure whether this is an issue caused by the WebView or the Emulator.

Comment: In Developer settings, which WebView Implementation is set to be used? Android System WebView or Chrome?

Comment: @Cheesebaron how or where can I check this?

Comment: On the device itself, in developer settings. Same place where you enable debugging.

Comment: OK. I found it. It's set to Android System WebView. How can I change this or add an additional one?

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Your hint pointed me in correct direction. I have simply installed a newer Android System WebViewer Version via APK.